# Inconsistent date formatting, possibly due to locale?

Tags: date, datetime, time, android

I've noticed that some users of my app are experiencing oddly formatted dates, and I am assuming it is due to locale reasons.  Can someone suggest a better way to achieve the expected result and/or explain how to properly deal with the (possible) locale issue?

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
String timeString = time.format("%b_%d_%Y_%I-%M-%S-%p");
```

Expected result:

```
Feb_12_2014_10-06-09-AM
```

From my logging I occasionally see results like this:

```
2?_12_2014_07-35-58-??
```

sadly I do not capture the locale info so I don't know the exact details.

edit: After trying the accepted solution here are the results for each locale on Android.

```
en_ca Feb_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
fr_CA févr._12_2014_10-49-52-AM
en_ca Feb_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
zh_CN 2?_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
zh 2?_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
en Feb_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
fr_FR févr._12_2014_10-49-52-AM
fr févr._12_2014_10-49-52-AM
de Feb._12_2014_10-49-52-AM
de_DE Feb._12_2014_10-49-52-AM
it_IT feb_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
ja 2?_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
ko_KR 2?_12_2014_10-49-52-??
ko 2?_12_2014_10-49-52-??
zh_CN 2?_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
<none> 2_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
zh_CN 2?_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
zh_TW 2?_12_2014_10-49-52-??
en_GB Feb_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
en_US Feb_12_2014_10-49-52-AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format your datetime strings. It has a [constructor that allows you to specify the `Locale`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29), for example `Locale.US`.

`Time.format()` always works with the current, user-chosen locale which may not be what you want.

Further reading: [Be wary of the default locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale)

Comment: Thanks, was able to determine root cause with this